# how to query from customer RevisionEntity in Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

i'm using  Hibernate Envers,my customer RevisionEntity is:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(SimpleListener.class)
@Table(name = "data_rev_info")
public class SimpleRevisionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name = "revision_id")
    private long id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column(name = "revision_timestamp")
    private Date timestamp;
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the timestamp
     */
    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    /**
     * @param timestamp the timestamp to set
     */
    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

i can use auditReader to get audit time of a specific revision id

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
Date date = auditReader.getRevisionDate(n);
```

if i add a additonal field in SimpleRevisionEntity, named actor(type is String),how to get this addtional field by using AuditReader? 
Also if i want to query audit logs generated in the last five minites,how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of the `actor` field, you need to find the revision entity. It's a normal entity, so you can simply look it up by id using Hibernate, or using the `AuditReader.findRevision(revisionEntityClass, revision)` method.

As to querying for revisions generated in the last 5 minutes, I would do a query on the revision entity specifying that the `timestamp` column must be `>= NOW()-5 minutes` (that's pseudo-code, of course :) ).

Comment: thank you for your answer,if i want to query whether a specific field(name) in a specific entity(Person) has been modified or not in last five minutes, how to?

Comment: first query all the revisions in the last five minutes,then for each revison use AuditEntity.property("name").hasChanged() ?

Comment: I would first find the revision number corresponding to "5 minutes ago", and then do a query: `auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(..., false, false).add(AE.property("name").hasChanged()).add(AE.revisionNumber().gt([found revision number])`